# -2002F Error on Macbook Internet Recovery

Tags: macos, mac, ethernet, macbook, macbook-pro

I have wiped the boot partition on my Macbook and I get the flashing folder with the `?`

I have rebooted holding down command + R where I get the spinning glove and the opportunity to select my Wifi network. I connect to Wifi with no problem. But I keep getting `-2002F` errors, after waiting for the laptop to connect to Apple

I want the Macbook to use the Ethernet connection instead. I have Ethernet cable connected via USB-C adaptor. I can see the adaptor light flash, indicating that Ethernet is recognised. But I am not given the opportunity to select it, at the spinning globe screen.

How can I work around this?

Comment: Bad internet connection. Use wired ethernet instead, report back.

Comment: I've plugged in the Macbook via ethernet. But I'm still greeted with the Wi-Fi spinning globe ball. I am not given the option to select ethernet connection.

Comment: I assumed it would auto-select it, as it's always preferable to wifi in any circumstance.

Comment: So would I, I even left it at that screen for a couple of hours, to no avail

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to this turned out to be disabling my router firewall.

Have a look at [this article](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/209063/os-x-internet-recovery-globe-stuck) over at AskDifferent for solutions if you get the same issue. There are a few good answers there.